# Tengo un TypeError en una funcion que estoy ejecutando

Tags: javascript

tengo un error en la siguente funcion, en la funcion debo realizar una algrupacion de el elemento "nota" que esta dentro del objeto estudiantes, para sumar todos los resultado y luego dividirlo por la cantidad de veces que se repita, es decir que debe etornar el promedio del curso, es decir, la suma de todas las notas divididas por el total de notas e imprimirlo en consola

```js
const estudiantes = [
    {
      id: 1,
      nombre: "Boby",
      apellido: "rodrigues",
      nota: 17,
      curso: "Spartan Developers",
      conducta: "Buena"
    }
,
    {
      id: 2,
      nombre: "Eliezer",
      apellido: "Gil",
      nota: 16,
      curso: "Spartan Developers",  
            conducta: "Buena" 
    },
      {
      id: 3 ,
      nombre: "Fabiana",
      apellido: "rodrigues",
      nota: 18,
      curso: "Spartan Developers",
            conducta: "Exelente"
        },
    {
      id: 4,
      nombre: "Rebeca",
      apellido: "Mendez",
      nota: 20,
      curso: "Spartan Developers",
            conducta: "Exelente"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      nombre: "Reiner",
      apellido: "Ramires",
      nota: 12,
      curso: "Spartan Developers",
            conducta: "Puede mejorar"
    },

    const promedioEscolar = (estudiante) => 
        estudiantes.map(({nota}) => { 
            let result = estudiantes.map.reduce((a, b) => a + b / 10);
         console.log(`El resultado de la funcion es: ${result}`);
         return result;
        })  
    }
    let resultpromedioEscolar = promedioEscolar(estudiantes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltaba cerrar el array y el resto del código es mucho más sencillo en realidad, quedaría algo así:

```
const estudiantes = [
{
    id: 1,
    nombre: "Boby",
    apellido: "rodrigues",
    nota: 17,
    curso: "Spartan Developers",
    conducta: "Buena",
},
{
    id: 2,
    nombre: "Eliezer",
    apellido: "Gil",
    nota: 16,
    curso: "Spartan Developers",
    conducta: "Buena",
},
{
    id: 3,
    nombre: "Fabiana",
    apellido: "rodrigues",
    nota: 18,
    curso: "Spartan Developers",
    conducta: "Exelente",
},
{
    id: 4,
    nombre: "Rebeca",
    apellido: "Mendez",
    nota: 20,
    curso: "Spartan Developers",
    conducta: "Exelente",
},
{
    id: 5,
    nombre: "Reiner",
    apellido: "Ramires",
    nota: 12,
    curso: "Spartan Developers",
    conducta: "Puede mejorar",
},
];

const promedioEscolar = (array) => {
const sumaNotas= array.reduce((a, b) => a + b.nota, 0);
console.log("El resultado promedio es: "+ sumaNotas /estudiantes.length)
return sumaNotas /estudiantes.length
};
```

La suma de todos las notas dividido el total de alumnos en el array, en este caso un total de 83 la suma de las notas, dando un resultado de 16.6 de promedio (83/5).

Espero sirva, quedo a las ordenes.

Comment: amigo y para dejar de molestar y ya si esto no se como hacerlo y es tener una validacion, si La conducta del estudiante es true y su nota es mayor a 10, entonces se imprima por consola un mensaje diciendo "El estudiante pasa de curso", en cambio, si la conducta del estudiante es false y sin importar su nota se imprima por consola "El estudiante reprueba el curso", y si la nota es menor a 10, tambien imprima "El estudiante reprueba el curso, se que se puede hacer con un :"for of" pero no se como hacerlo, me podía ayudar

Comment: Por normas del sitio no podemos hacer ejercicios completos, solo ayudar a resolver problemas específicos. Una guía, poner cunducta en false/true sin ", luego un forof puede ser. Por cada alumno de estudiantes, si alumno.conducta && alumno.nota >= 10 hago  console.log(alumno.nombre+" "+alumno.apellido+"-Aprobado") sino hago console.log(alumno.nombre+" "+alumno.apellido+"-No Aprobado"). Sería suficiente, si no te sale agrega lo q intentaste a la pregunta o crea otra y te ayudamos. Favor marcar como solución la respuesta dando al visto al costado de la misma si resolvió tu duda.

Comment: El marcar las respuestas como solución es de suma importancia, no solo para quien se toma el tiempo para ayudar, sino para que cuando otros busquen temas similares, sepan que la propuesta sirve y puedan reutilizarla, recuerda que para darla como solucionada, debes darle click en el visto que aparece al costado de la respuesta. (En la respuesta misma con el código, no en los comentarios). Gracias.

Comment: const validacion = (estudiantes) => {

    for( notas of nota){
   if (alumno.conducta && alumno.nota >= 10){
       console.log(alumno.nombre+""+alumno.apellido+"-Aprobado")
       break
   }
   if (alumno.conducta && alumno.nota =< 10)
   console.log(alumno.nombre+""+alumno.apellido+"- No Aprobado")
       break
}
validacion(estudiantes)

Comment: const validacion = (estudiantes) => { for( const alumno of estudiantes){ if (alumno.conducta && alumno.nota >= 10){ console.log(alumno.nombre+""+alumno.apellido+"-Aprobado") } else { console.log(alumno.nombre+""+alumno.apellido+"- No Aprobado") }}} validacion(estudiantes)

Comment: Insisto, favor marcar ambas respuestas como solucionadas si consideras fueron útiles para resolver tu problema, sino es así ponte en contacto. Votarlas no es lo mismo que darlas como solución. Gracias.